# What's the pythonic idiom for creating a list of text items?

Tags: python, string, list, initialization

Often I have lists of constant text values that I want to put into a list. I certainly do not want to be typing lots of commas and quotation marks myself!

I've settled on this idiom: using triple-quotes to create a multi-line string that has one text entry on each line, thus creating a string constant with newline characters in it (from when I press ), and then I split on newline and remove the first and last line of the string which are blank (just newlines):

```
colors = """
black
brown
Salmon
red
Orange Red
Dark Goldenrod
Dark Olive Green
Chartreuse
navy
blue
Deep Pink
Dark Violet
""".split("\n")[1:-1]
```

Does somebody have a *better* way?

Comment: You should consider a proper IDE like PyCharm which lets you do fancy stuff like multi-line editing. That makes it really easy to just write all words in separate lines, and then wrap them all in quotes and add commas in one go.

Comment: Thanks @schwobaseggl. Yes, I always look for the best, but lightest, editor that complements the language I'm writing in. But in parallel, I like to also know how to use the language elegantly when I (or my students) are using the default, ubiquitous editor as well.

Comment: I don't think there's a much more elegant way than what you are doing other than maybe using a different separator char then line breaks. You could avoid the slicing by not adding the first and last newline to begin with, but that would not improve readability.

Comment: "Better" how? This is inevitably going to be opinion-based.

Comment: I think a cleaner way is to put all your colors in a config file and load that file into a string using a simple function. This would be much more reusable.

Comment: You can also trim whitespace before splitting with an LF like `.strip().split("\n")`.

Comment: @Ash -- config file -- can you give me an example of how that looks / is done in Python so I can learn?

Comment: I would also consider code clarity - an actual list in the code is easier for someone new to understand what the data is for and how it will be used (even yourself a year from now!), than a string which you're then splitting. You'd want to avoid people thinking "Oh it's just a string" and doing something which breaks your processing

Comment: I think something like colors=loadColor(fileName) is even clearer since it makes the code more modular. But in this case I admit it might be a tad overkill.

Comment: Thanks for all the great comments. From the responses I learned the various considerations (and opinions) for what is "better" and I can make my decisions based on them. Probably different decision depending on the context. Note that with beginning students I may forgo the config file because their dealing with two source files has proven confusing at first. Certainly, for modular programming, it is a good way to go, and thanks for the simple ways to do it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no official or unofficial "idiom" other than the list initializer. It's readable enough (one of the Python's goals is readability) to not need anything else for the purpose of code comprehensibility in the general case.

If that's not good enough for you, feel free to use whatever you can think of that is more convenient. Some options:

- The split multiline string you gave is just fine
- If your list is very long (to the point it hurts code readability by taking very much space), it may be moved into a separate file (again, the format is whatever is convenient for you to work with, do not overthink it)

Comment: I accepted this response as the answer because it summarizes and justifies the other response, which themselves are much appreciated as detail.

Answer (score 1):

Adding an answer as requested by @talkaboutquality in the comments. What I ment by a config file is really simple, and I made that suggestion by assuming that in bigger projects (even if it's only for your students), it is really unclean/messy to have a long list of parameters passed as a string inside the source code. So my suggestion is a simple as this:

```
#content of config.txt
black
brown
Salmon
red
Orange Red
Dark Goldenrod
Dark Olive Green
Chartreuse
navy
blue
Deep Pink
Dark Violet
```

Now, from your python code

```
fn=open("config.txt");
lines=fn.readlines();
colors=[x.strip() for x in lines];
```

Of course, you can encapsulate this three lines of code in a function like `loadColor(fn)`, which will make it clear for your students. This way, you can add/remove colors without ever modifying your source code. This is primarily opinion based I think, and maybe I've just picked up this habit from working on C++ projects where having config files in the form of key/values or scripts (*e.g* lua scripts) makes life easier.

Comment: since the OP is looking to use a language more elegantly, perhaps `with open('config.txt') as f: colors = [x.strip() for x in f]` ?

Answer (score 0):

Here is one alternative that prints the list above.

```
colors = ("black,brown,Salmon,red,Orange Red,Dark Goldenrod,"
          "Dark Olive Green,Chartreuse,navy,blue,Deep Pink,Dark Violet"
          .split(','))
for color in colors:
    print(color)
```

Comment: Thanks @terry-jan-reedy but it's still much easier for me to hit <Enter> than type commas.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest solution is just to use a spaces and .split().

Note that python strings will be automatically concatenated if they are part of a single parenthetical grouping. See the following:

```
colors = ("white blue black red green "
"teal pink orange").split()
print(colors)
```

`['white', 'blue', 'black', 'red', 'green', 'teal', 'pink', 'orange']`

If you have spaces in your individual strings you're best off using another character to separate them. I like '-', personally.
EG:

```
colors = ('white-black-blue-dark orange-chartruse-'
"green-robin's egg blue").split('-')
print(colors)
```

`['white',
 'black',
 'blue',
 'dark orange',
 'chartruse',
 'green',
 "robin's egg blue"]`

If you really want every string on a separate line, why not use triple quotes as so:

```
'''white
blue
dark orange'''.split('\n')
```

Then you avoid having any blank entries in the list.